# Advertising for a post-doc positing in gaming

Tags: discussion

Clearly gamedev is not a good place to advertise a post-doctoral position which focuses on certain aspects of game development.  Problem is, I don't really know of good places (which do not charge exhorbitant fees) to do so.  I do think the people on gamedev do know the answer to this, but it would be improper for me to ask directly - thus the question here on Meta!

So: where would be good places to post [an ad for a game-related post-doc position?](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg92680.html)

---

EDIT: I am aware of [Gamasutra's jobs board](http://www.gamasutra.com/jobs/), [gamedev's careers hub](http://www.gamedev.net/hub/careers), [gamesindustry.biz's job board](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/jobs/?search=4264), as well as [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).  But these all charge non-trivial fees, without offering any certainty that anyone with a relevant PhD might be reading the ad.  Where else?

Comment: Considering your implementation language is *Haskell*, that kinda further reduces the market - I think the Haskell mailing list your post is on, is the best you're going to get.

Comment: Anyone who manages to get a 'relevant' PhD can learn *Haskell* in very little time.  The current work has all been done by (good) undergraduate students, none of whom knew Haskell when they started their work.

Comment: Minus the link to the actual ad, this seems like a reasonable question for the main site. Why is it here and not there? (With the link to the actual ad, this is no more appropriate for meta than the main site - meta is not an anything-goes forum any more than the main site is.)

Comment: Do others agree with Joe?  In which case, without the actual link to the ad, I will post it.  But I would rather not post it, just to see it closed and bounced back to meta...

Comment: "Where can one find and post ads for post-doctoral positions in game development?" seems very much in-line with the other questions we have about hiring, e.g. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2374, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/282. I might suggest expanding the range from "post-doctoral" to "academic" and make it CW - that way it can attract related things like graduate fellowships as well.

Answer (score 3):

[StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), maybe? I don't know how what they charge compares to other venues... but it's an option. GDNet also has a [Careers](http://www.gamedev.net/hub/careers/) section that appears to already contain a fair number of academic positions.

Comment: StackOverflow Careers charges $350/ad, GameDev charges $185/ad.  We just don't have that kind of budget for academic positions!  Normally there are all sorts of free channels to advertise for post-doc positions, but gaming is 'different'.  If I was fairly certain that there were sufficiently many PhDs reading these posts, I would find the money, somehow.  But I am not even sure that these sites actually reach the 'right' market. [Gamasutra's jobs board and gamesindustry.biz also charge fees]

Comment: As far as I know, there are no PhDs among the most-active members of the Game Development SE, at least. Game development doesn't tend to attract that many academics.

Comment: True, but that seems to be changing 'rapidly', with quite a few academic programs being set up in the last few years.  I do know a couple of people who did get a PhD for game-related work.  So I am still optimistic.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest spreading the word at relevant schools and universities. Surely they are amenable to free listings for postdoc positions, and that's the correct audience for these positions, yes?

Comment: Indeed.  But there is no 'easy' way to reach that audience.  So I figured I would ask here, the second-closest audience.